# Dynamic Menu Display Partitions Using Dialog

Tags: bash, dialog, disk

```
#!/bin/bash

NUMBER_LINE="$(lsblk | awk '/sda[1-99]/ { print }' | wc -l)"
for (( i = 1; i <= $NUMBER_LINE; i++ )); do
    DISK="$(lsblk | grep sda[1-99] | awk ' NR==$i{ print $1 }' | cut -c7-)"
    MENU+="Ligne$i disk$DISK "
done

dialog --menu "test" 10 60 2 $MENU
```

I want my code to display all my disks with dialog menu output but the $i isn't effective. Is there a way to make it work ?

Comment: The `$i` is not getting expanded because you have it in single quotes. Try `awk ' NR=='$i'{ print $1 }'`.

Comment: Whoa dude, you just saved the day ! Single quote... Bash will never cease to amaze me haha !

Comment: Also, the regular expression `sda[1-99]` isn't matching what you (seem to) think it does. The `[1-99]` part is defining a set of characters to match, namely the set of characters from `'1'` through `'9'`, plus the character `'9'` (which is obviously redundant). You can see this by typing `echo "sda99" | grep --color=always 'sda[1-99]'` on the command line, and taking note of the highlighted portion (assuming you have a color terminal, of course). To match anything between `"sda1"` and `"sda99"`, you would probably want to do something more like `grep 'sda[1-9][0-9]'`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That's what I was expecting from the community. Your improvements are well noticed brother. If I could by you a beer trust me I would have ! And I think the correct regex expression would be sda[1-9].*[0-9] if I'm not wrong

Comment: The `[1-99]` portion of your regular expression is what's called a character class, and it's important to note that by itself (that is, unless you follow it with a [repetition operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) such as `*` or `+`, etc), a character class only ever matches a *single* character. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for more information.